# How to get the range of a row cell based on the values presence in excel VB Macros?

Tags: excel

I am new to excel VBA. I am trying to get the row range dynamically based on the data presence. For example if I have Values present in G1(value 'A') H1 ( Value '2') I1(Value '3') I need to select the values from G1 to I1. Some times I might have till K1 or L1 . The formula has to fetch the values till empty column.  Please let me know the formula to get it.

Thanks
Murali

Answer (score -1):

There are a few solutions using VBA. Below are two. The first assumes your data starts in cell A2 and all columns contain data up to your last column. This method identifies the last column by starting from the left.

```vb
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim myRange as range

lastColumn = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    
With ws
    Set myRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, lastColumn))
End With
```

A second option if your row may include some blank cells is to identify the last used column by starting from the right.

```vb
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim myRange as range

lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
With ws
    Set myRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(1, lastColumn))
End With
```